# Properly modify home dir

Tags: home-directory, users

I would like to know, whow to modify **properly** the homedir of a user.

I already know about this command

```
usermod -d /home/peter peter
```

But now, do I have to create the homedir before?
And what will happen to the old homedir? (I know about the -m option which would move the contents, but I don't want to move/remove the old content).

So for not removing and just leaving the old content, would I just have to use the command, exactly as I mentioned above?

I use Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS "Server".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Firstly usermod can not be run as a normal user.  You either need to be logged on as root, not recommended, or prefix the command with sudo.  The command does not create the folder so you will need to create it first.

```
cd /home;
sudo mkdir peter
sudo chown peter:peter peter
sudo usermod -d /home/peter peter
```

Will do what you want.  Any existing home folder will remain unchanged

You cannot change a user's home directory while that user is logged in (if you are logged in as `peter`, it will not work).

Comment: What do I do when it says the user is logged in?
But for real the user is not logged in. Users just shows myself.

Comment: you can check who you are logged with `whoami` and everybody logged in with `who`.

Comment: I used `users` and it just returned my own name. Which was not the username, which I assigned the new home directory to. Seems to me the user was somehow assigned to me, because after re-login it worked well.

Comment: small notice that moduser will ``move`` old dir to new dir, so it will not create new dir if old dir does not exist. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/usermod.8.html

Comment: `sudo chown peter: peter` might be preferable here. This form `<user>:` uses the user's default group, which is not necessarily the same name as the user name.

Comment: What would happen if I directly edit `/etc/passwd`? Is that unsafe?

Comment: @SridharSarnobat You can directly edit `/etc/passwd` with `sudo vipw` which will safely lock the file while you're editing it. Next time the user logs in, they will come into their new home directory.