# Special directory permissions for new user

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

I need to add special permission for new shell user.
After using `adduser` command new, the user can read all directories into shell account.

Command `adduser user1` brings us new user which has own shell directory `/home/user1`.
Now, I need make permissions for `user1` with full access only for its corresponding `/home/user1` folder. Each time when `user1` goes into `/home` folder, the user should not see anything from this folder. Same behaviour should be when `user1` goes into main shell directory where we have folders `etc`, `home`, `usr`, `var` etc.

Now when I log in as `user1` I can read all shell directories e.g. via Midnight Commander.

Can anybody help to set this special permissions? Thank You in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to hide some directory for a specific user?

Comment: Yes! Because when he use  Midnight Commander, he can browse directories from entire server. I need to make he can browse only own shell `/home/user1` folder.

Answer (score 1):

To use a system a user must be able to access/read many parts of the system. But he will not be able to write outside of his own home directory (i.e. `/home/user1`).

This of course should not apply to the home directories of other users. (Supposedly for convenience) Ubuntu comes with a default setting where everybody has **read** access to all home directories of other users.

`ls -l /home` will show something like

```
drwxr-xr-x  54 user      user      4096 Jan 25 17:17 user
drwxr-xr-x  52 user1     user1     4096 Dez 21 17:47 user1
drwxr-xr-x 198 another   another  12288 Jan 25 17:19 another
```

Look at the permissions at the beginning of each line:

```
drwxr-xr-x
       ^^^
```

The marked part means: "Everybody else can read the directory **and** `cd` into it"

You can prevent this by issuing

```
sudo chmod 0700 /home/*
```

check with `ls -l /home`
and you will see something like

```
drwx------  54 user      user      4096 Jan 25 17:17 user
drwx------  52 user1     user1     4096 Dez 21 17:47 user1
drwx------ 198 another   another  12288 Jan 25 17:19 another
```

Now no user will be able to see the contents of another user`s home directory (of course neither with Midnight Commander).

If you want to prevent this issue for newly added users there are several ways, depending on how you create the new user.

#### When you add new users with the GUI (System Settings/Users)

This takes the permissions on the home directory from the existing permissions on `etc/skel`. So

```
sudo chmod -v 0700 /etc/skel
```

will give the desired result.

#### When you add new users with `adduser`

Edit `/etc/adduser.conf`. Find the line

```
DIR_MODE=0755
```

and change it to

```
DIR_MODE=0750
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using different permissions.  Presumably, if you remove read permissions to `/home` for others and for the group.  This way, only the superuser will have access to read.

I tested this by creating a new user for which I assigned a folder other than the default folder.  As I was testing, I did in a folder other than my system's `/home` folder in case I messed up.  Here is the step-by-step of what I did and it seems to have worked:

1. I created a folder `/private_home`
2. Under `/private_home` I created another folder called `user1`.
3. Created a standard user called `user1`.
4. Assigned folder  `/private_home/user1` as the home folder for the user using: `sudo usermod -d /private_home/user1 user1`.  This moves the home folder of `user1` from `/home/user1` to `/private_home/user1`.
5. Then changed the access privileges to `/private_home` as follows: `sudo chmod 711 /private_home`.

Now, when login in as `user1` using `su user1` I logged into that user's folder `/private_home/user1` but when I try `cd ..` I am able to get to that folder (the shell prompts shows that) but I have no permissions to read the folder contents.  That is, when trying `ls` it says `Permission denied'.

Presumably you can do the same thing for all your users for that `/private_home` folder.

**Having said so, I would not do this with** `/` **as you will run the risk to make your system unstable**.

Note: I used some of the concepts in [the answer in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250862/properly-modify-home-dir).